# Why does $\sqrt{1 + 4x^2} > 2|x| \implies -1 - \sqrt{1 + 4x^2} < -2x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $f(x) = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}{2x}$, if $x > 0$, show that $f(x) < -1$.
>
> Solution: Note that $\sqrt{1 + 4x^2} > 2|x|$. So if $x > 0$, then $-1 - \sqrt{1 + 4x^2} < -2x$. Thus $f(x) < -1$.

I don't understand where they got $-1 - \sqrt{1 + 4x^2} < -2x$ from. Using the fact that $\sqrt{1 + 4x^2} > 2|x|$, if $x > 0$, then we have $\sqrt{1 + 4x^2} > 2x \implies -\sqrt{1 + 4x^2} < -2x$. How do you get the extra $-1$ constant without changing one side of the inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $-f(x) < A$, then $-f(x) - 1 < A$, too, because $-f(x) - 1 < -f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
x>0&\implies&0&<2x\\
&\implies&4x^2-2x+1&<1+4x^2\\
&\implies&(2x-1)^2&<1+4x^2\\
&\implies&2x-1\leq|2x-1|&<\sqrt{1+4x^2}\\
&\implies&-1-\sqrt{1+4x^2}&<-2x
\end{align*}